# When creating my gh-pages page, my images are not displaying my slider when I visit the site

Tags: github-pages

I don't have jekyll in my project and all my files are Case-Sensitive so they are displaying in the correct order offline when running gulp locally, but when pushed to gh-pages broken image icons display

http://imgur.com/uUajk.png

and here is the site when it is hosted on gh-pages.
http://badview08.github.io/colonialLife/

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your site and it seems the error is:

```
GET http://badview08.github.io/dist/img/slide1.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

If you go to that URL, you get the expected `404`.

However, if you change it to `http://badview08.github.io/colonialLife/dist/img/slide1.jpg` it correctly finds the image.

In your markup, I would change `src='/dist/img/slide1.jpg'` to either:

`src='colonialLife/dist/img/slide1.jpg'` (correct sub directory)

or

`src='./dist/img/slide1.jpg'` (relative pathing)